# Count words between all <strong> elements in div ID

Tags: jquery

I can't count's all words in all strong elements.
My example http://szymoon.nazwa.pl/jquery/index3.html

```
$(function() {
  var text = $.trim($('#strongdiv strong').text());
  var charsLength = text.length;
  var wordsCount = text.html().split(/\s+/).length;
  alert(wordsCount);
});
```

> Hir is 10 words
>   <#>We have here 8 words and 35 chars<#> <#>sd sa<#>

but my script tell that i have 9.

If u have any suggestions will be nice.

Comment: Post your script (fiddle) and it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: Look your console: `Uncaught TypeError: Object We have here 8 words and 35 charsasd sa has no method 'html' `

Comment: That was not the only issue :)

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/WxYTe/)

```
$(function() {
  var text, charsLength=0,wordsCount=0;
  $('#strongdiv strong').each(function() {
    text = $.trim($(this).text());
    charsLength += text.length;
    wordsCount += text.split(/\s+/).length;
  });
  $("#output").append("words"+wordsCount+"<br/>chars: "+charsLength);
});
```